# Pivot in text mode (no X) (Pivot = rotated 90 degrees)

Tags: linux, video, console, framebuffer

How to get rotated video in text mode (no X), even during booting sequence ?

OS: Linux

Graphics card: mostly ATI, but curious about NVida and Intel solutions.

Comment: What's your OS? Bootloader? Graphics chip might matter too.

Answer (score 3):

See the [fbcon documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt).  Basically:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate  # normal
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate  # clockwise
echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate  # counterclockwise
```

You can add the kernel parameter `fbcon=rotate:1` to achieve the same thing at boot.